# Get all the integer type from a repo into a list of an existing object

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure a way to loop through a repository that will get all the `CourseId`values. So far I have only been able to get the first value found, but not all of them as a list. How would I be able to get all the values as a list, and is this where I should be looping?

Here is what I have done so far

```
StudentVM studentVm = new StudentVM();
            studentVm.Student = StudentRepository.Get(id);
            //Loop here?
            studentVm.SelectedCourseIds = new List<int>() {
                studentVm.Student.Courses.Select(x => x.CourseId).FirstOrDefault()
            };
            studentVm.SetCourseItems(CourseRepository.GetAll());
            studentVm.SetMajorItems(MajorRepository.GetAll());
            studentVm.SetStateItems(StateRepository.GetAll());
            return View(studentVm);
```

Comment: Replace `FirstOrDefault()` with `ToList()`?

Comment: it says it cannot convert 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `ToList()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()`. And also remove the `new List` portion since `ToList()` will already return a list:

```
studentVm.SelectedCourseIds = studentVm.Student.Courses.Select(x => x.CourseId).ToList();
```

Comment: It took me a while to figure that out.